# Why did mysqldump SET user-defined variables without at-signs?

Tags: sql, mariadb, syntax-error, prepared-statement

I came upon this error while attempting to restore a database dump to a MariaDB database:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1234: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'v_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET v_sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF' at line 7
```

After reading up on SQL syntax, I came to the conclusion that what failed is a [SET statement](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set/) where the [user-defined variable](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/) name is not preceded by an `@`, as it must be. But why would `mysqldump` generate such a statement in the first place?

The statement used to create the dump is

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --single-transaction --routines --triggers --all-databases > dump.sql
```

with

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.19 Distrib 10.5.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

and then restored on

```
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.48-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

The full definition from the dump is:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`mydefiner`@`%` PROCEDURE `p_my_procedure`(
IN `myid` VARCHAR(36)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE v_sql TEXT;
SET v_sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ', '`prefix_',myid,'_one`;');
PREPARE stmt FROM v_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET v_sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ','`prefix_',myid,'_two`;');
PREPARE stmt FROM v_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET v_sql = CONCAT('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ','`other_prefix_',myid,'`;');
PREPARE stmt FROM v_sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END ;;
```

Comment: Provide SP texts from SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE and from the dump.

Comment: @Akina I added the definition from the dump.

Comment: And where are the same definitions received from SHOW statements? The statements from the dump are obviously errorneous and contradicts [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/prepare-statement/) which claims "*preparable_stmt is either a string literal or a user variable (**not a local variable**, an SQL expression or a subquery) that contains the text of the statement.*"

Comment: A much quicker way to write these is a single line [execute immediate](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/) with a `concat` directly there. Might work around your problem, however I'm still keen to see it.

Comment: @danblack Destination server is 10.1.48-MariaDB, and it does not support `execute immediate`.

Comment: @Akina To be clear, I should run `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE p_my_procedure` after attempting to restore the dump? Or on the source database?

Comment: @Akina If the former, I get `ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE p_my_procedure does not exist`. That seems reasonable to me because the restore fails while trying to prepare this statement.

Comment: You must execute `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE p_my_procedure` on **source** server.

Comment: I don't think it was mysqldump that omitted the @ sign from variable name! Declare statements are used for local variables, not for user defined variables.

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I realized since posting that the actual problem seems to be that the dump correctly declares local variables, but as Akina mentioned they *should* be user-defined variables.

Comment: Well, you need to fix the source!

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the clarification! The `Create Procedure` part is the exact same as the definition I posted, without `DELIMITER ;;` and the final `;;`. Is that it?

Comment: @Shadow So, it looks like the source of the problem is that someone stored this 
illegal procedure in the first place? I would accept that for an answer. I'm still a bit confused on how that original store succeeded, but this attempt to replicate it doesn't, 
further comments on that appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the dump was created on a server > 10.1.48 (you use mysqldump from 10.5 server package). Also consider to upgrade, 10.1 is eoled.